# Retiring in UK, is my tax free Australian superannuation income taxed in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, australia, pension

I'm a dual UK/Australia citizen and seriously thinking of moving to UK permanently.  I am 57 and when I turn 60 I will be able to get a tax free pension income or a lump sum from my Australian superannuation.  The question is, would either of those be taxable in the UK?

Comment: You say you’re thinking of moving permanently, will that mean you will be resident in the UK under the Statutory Residence Test? https://www.litrg.org.uk/tax-guides/migrants/what-uk-tax-do-i-pay-my-overseas-pension

Comment: Yes I would be domiciled and tax resident in the UK.  I assume the income from my Australian tax free superannuation income would be fully taxable in the UK but I wanted to check.